Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of function 'function () { [native code] } - Fastify Swagger
I created a simple financial API for a graduation project and I am trying to use Swagger to document the API, but its occurring this error on the Swagger. Can someone help me?
Error in question:
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of function 'function () { [native code] }'"
}

My code:
import fastify from 'fastify';

import {
  serializerCompiler,
  validatorCompiler,
  type ZodTypeProvider,
} from 'fastify-type-provider-zod'

import fastifyCors from '@fastify/cors'
import fastifySwagger from '@fastify/swagger'
import fastifySwaggerUi from '@fastify/swagger-ui'


const app = fastify().withTypeProvider<ZodTypeProvider>()

app.register(fastifyCors, {
  origin: '*',
})

app.setValidatorCompiler(validatorCompiler)
app.setSerializerCompiler(serializerCompiler)

app.register(fastifySwagger, {
  swagger: {
    info: {
      title: 'API de Transações e Projeções',
      description: 'Documentação da API',
      version: '1.0.0',
    },
    schemes: ['http'],
    consumes: ['application/json'],
    produces: ['application/json'],
  }
})

app.register(fastifySwaggerUi, {
  routePrefix: '/docs',
  uiConfig: {
    docExpansion: 'full',
    deepLinking: false,
  }
})


app.listen({
  port: process.env.PORT ? Number(process.env.PORT) : 3333
}).then(() => {
  console.log('HTTP server running')
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT ? Number(process.env.PORT) : 3333}`)
})

I tried using Swagger to document a fastify API but I am getting an error that I cannot comprehend.

const express = require('express');
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const app = express();
